# Android: accessing all checkboxes in onclick event of a checkbox in custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onclick

how can I access all the checkboxes in my listview from the onclick event of a given checkbox. What I want to achieve is to disable all unckecked checkboxes when the number of checked checkboxes in greater than a given number.

Thanks you!

```
public class FriendAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayout;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private int mNameIndex;
    private int mIdIndex;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater; 
    private final ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();  

    private final class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView image;
        public CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    public FriendAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.mCursor = c;
        this.mNameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(WhipemDBAdapter.KEY_NAME);
        this.mIdIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(WhipemDBAdapter.KEY_FB_ID);
        this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);        
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
                viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_pic);
                viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            String name = mCursor.getString(mNameIndex);
            String fb_id = mCursor.getString(mIdIndex);         
            boolean isChecked = ((GlobalVars) mContext.getApplicationContext()).isFriendSelected(fb_id);

            viewHolder.name.setText(name);
            imageDownloader.download("http://graph.facebook.com/"+fb_id+"/picture", viewHolder.image);

            viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(fb_id);
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) v;
        String fb_id = (String) cBox.getTag();

        /* 
            How can I access all the checkboxes here?
        */

        if (cBox.isChecked()) {
            if (!((GlobalVars) mContext.getApplicationContext()).isFriendSelected(fb_id))
                ((GlobalVars) mContext.getApplicationContext()).addSelectedFriend(fb_id);
        } else {
            if (((GlobalVars) mContext.getApplicationContext()).isFriendSelected(fb_id))
                ((GlobalVars) mContext.getApplicationContext()).removeSelectedFriend(fb_id);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use [onCheckChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) instead of `onClickListener`. Keep a global counter for the number of friends checked, and set its value in the constructor itself. Next in the `onCheckedChanged` method increment or decrement the counter based on whether the checkbox has been checked or not. If the counter becomes more than your count then invalidate the listview and in the getview method set the checkbox's visibility as invisible (or gone)

Comment: If I want to disable the unchecked checkboxes as soon as the limit is reached, I must do it in onClick (or onCheckChangedListener), right? How can I access all the checkboxes from the onClick event, how can I get all the children in the ListView.

Comment: yes. As for accessing set some global flag indicating that unchecked boxes should be invisible, call listview.invalidate()

Comment: how can I get the listview in my adapter?

Comment: make it a global variable or pass it as an argument to the constructor of the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by getting a global reference of the view in the getView method.

so it should be something like this:

```
View myRow;
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
myRow=convertView;

//all other stuff
}
```

After that, supposing the root view of your ListView row is a RelativeLayout, you can try to use this code in the onClick method:

```
RelativeLayout rowRootView=(RelativeLayout)myRow.getRootView();
for(int i=0;i<rowRootView.getChildCount();i++){
    if(rowRootView.getChildAt(i).getClass()==CheckBox.class){
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Maybe it should work also with this code

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RelativeLayout rowRootView=(RelativeLayout)v.getRootView();
        for(int i=0;i<rowRootView.getChildCount();i++){
        if(rowRootView.getChildAt(i).getClass()==CheckBox.class){
        //do your stuff
        }
         }
    }
```

hope this help